# I cannot find tags for Selenium on VBA in our ERP softwares HTML

Tags: html, vba, google-chrome, selenium, tags

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. I'm almost brand new to Selenium and I'm moderately experienced on VBA. I've been building code to go into our companies ERP system, sign in based on variables in an excel sheet, and through a series of mouse clicks export all the current dimensional data for any given customer.

So far, I've been able to get Chrome to open from VBA and I can get logged in. However, once I get into the actual system which uses session IDs, there are no tags that work. [I've attached a picture of my HTML code and the screen I'm working in, but it will only let me post a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpBT9.jpg)

I've tried using Xpath, link text, partial link text, ect. to no avail. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Assert As New Assert
Private driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub SiteLodgin()

driver.Get "https://www.intacct.com/ia/acct/login.phtml"

Dim CompIn As Variant
Dim UserIn As Variant
Dim PassIn As Variant

CompIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Passwords").Range("B1:B1000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Start").Range("B1"), Sheets("Passwords").Range("a1:a1000"), 0), 1)
driver.FindElementById("company").SendKeys CompIn

UserIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Passwords").Range("c1:c1000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Start").Range("B1"), Sheets("Passwords").Range("a1:a1000"), 0), 1)
driver.FindElementById("login").SendKeys UserIn

PassIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Passwords").Range("d1:d1000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Start").Range("B1"), Sheets("Passwords").Range("a1:a1000"), 0), 1)
driver.FindElementById("passwd").SendKeys PassIn

driver.FindElementById("retbutton").Click


Call MessageBox_vbOKOnly

//Here is where I'm failing. I have to do a bit of human interaction here because of text verification, but I have the message box set up to pause the code.//

//First, I know that the window is called win_ser_1 but when I tried to switch to it, I got an error.//

driver.SwitchToWindowByName ("win_ser_1")

//Here is the xpath that I tried using and this also failed//

driver.FindElementByXPath ("//div[@id='mainmenu']/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/span[2]")

End Sub

Sub MessageBox_vbOKOnly()
Dim OutPut As Integer
OutPut = MsgBox("Click once client is loaded", vbOKOnly, "Example of vbOKOnly")
End Sub
```

---

So any help you can give would be so appreciated. I understand that it would be easier if I could provide the actual website, but it has client info on it so that's not possible. If there is a super good Samaritan out there that would be willing to screenshare with me, I can schedule that. Thanks for your time.

NOTE*** It has to be in Chrome

Comment: I am not familiar with automation in Chrome, I do have experience in IE which I know won't help you. But I can at least give you a tip for your **Human Interaction** section (text verification). Instead of using a message box, I much better behind the scenes approach would be for you to wait until chrome becomes busy (in IE it would be `IE.Busy`), meaning that the user clicked to accept.... `Do Until ChromeObj.Busy_ DoEvents_ Loop`. (likely not the proper syntax, you get the point though).

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.